# PrintManager.print() and changed locale in attachBaseContext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-print-framework

Im using this extension to change the locale of my app:

```
fun Context.changeLanguage(language: String): ContextWrapper {
    var context = this
    val config = context.resources.configuration

    if (language.isNotBlank()) {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale)
        } else {
            config.locale = locale
        }
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
    }
    return ContextWrapper(context)
}
```

MainActivity:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase?.changeLanguage(prefs.language))
}
```

This works fine for everything but printing. 
When I try to print I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can print only from an activity`

PrintFragment in another module:

```
activity?.also { context ->
    val printManager = context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
    val jobName = getString(R.string.print_document)
    printManager.print(jobName, PrintPdfAdapter(context, printList), null)
}
```

Any ideas how I can get around this problem?

I switched back to `context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)` for now. Hoping they don't remove it too soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the original context from `fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?)` to some `MainActivity` variable and then in your `PrintFragment` use this variable for printing.

Same as here: [Android N: PrintManager.print() results in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can print only from an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680909/android-n-printmanager-print-results-in-java-lang-illegalstateexception-can/43680994)